# ReadFile is blocking when trying to capture cmd.exe output

Tags: c++, winapi, process

I am writing a C++ routine to spawn a process synchronously and return the output in as string. I realize that it can be done with `popen` but I would like it to happen silently on Windows. (No console window popup.) Nevertheless, I would like it to be call-compatible with the `popen` and `system` functions. These functions apparently pass output directly to `cmd.exe` and do not require `cmd /c` to be prepended to a command like `dir c:/mydir`. Here is my code:

```cpp
static bool _GetCmdExeFullPath(std::basic_string<WCHAR>& result)
{
   WCHAR sysDir[MAX_PATH];

   // Get the system directory
   if (GetSystemDirectoryW(sysDir, MAX_PATH) == 0) {
      // Handle error
      return false;
   }

   result = sysDir;
   result += L"\\cmd.exe";

   return true;
}

bool __process_execute(const std::string& cmd, std::string& processOutput)
{
   std::basic_string<WCHAR> cmdExe;
   if (! _GetCmdExeFullPath(cmdExe))
      return false;

   SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;
   HANDLE hRead, hWrite;

   saAttr.nLength = sizeof(saAttr);
   saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
   saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

   if (!CreatePipe(&hRead, &hWrite, &saAttr, 0))
   {
      //std::cerr << "Error: Unable to create pipe" << std::endl;
      return false;
   }

   STARTUPINFOW si;
   PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

   ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
   si.cb = sizeof(si);
   si.hStdError = hWrite;
   si.hStdOutput = hWrite;
   si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
   si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;

   ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

   const std::basic_string<WCHAR> wCmd = __utf8_to_WCHAR(cmd.c_str());

   // We have to cast away const here because the API doesn't specify const. But it also does not modify the string.
   //if (!CreateProcessW(NULL, const_cast<LPWSTR>(wCmd.c_str()), NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
   if (!CreateProcessW(cmdExe.c_str(), const_cast<LPWSTR>(wCmd.c_str()), NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
   {
      DWORD error = GetLastError();
      //std::cerr << "Error: Unable to create process" << std::endl;
      CloseHandle(hRead);
      CloseHandle(hWrite);
      return false;
   }

   CloseHandle(hWrite);

   DWORD bytesRead;
   const int bufferSize = 4096;
   char buffer[bufferSize];
   std::string output = "";

   while (true)
   {
      if (!ReadFile(hRead, buffer, bufferSize - 1, &bytesRead, NULL) || bytesRead == 0)
      {
         break;
      }

      buffer[bytesRead] = '\0';
      output += buffer;
   }

   CloseHandle(hRead);

   WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

   CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
   CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);

   std::basic_string<WCHAR> wOutput = __char_to_WCHAR(output.c_str());
   processOutput = __WCHAR_to_utf8(wOutput.c_str());

   return true;
}
```

I am passing in a command string of "dir \"c:/Program Files\"" which returns ~1800 bytes.

The problem is that `ReadFile` is blocking after reading the first 128 bytes. I can change the `CreateProcessW` call to pass NULL for `lpApplicationName` (as in the comment) and then it works (no blocking) if I prepend `cmd /c` to the input command string. But I would like not to have to do that.

EDIT: Moved call of `CloseHandle(hWrite)` to the correct location. This was a left-over artifact of debugging that did not affect the problem or its solution.

Comment: From [the documentation of `CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw), regarding the `lpCommandLine` parameter: "The Unicode version of this function, CreateProcessW, can modify the contents of this string. Therefore, this parameter cannot be a pointer to read-only memory [...]"

Comment: Identifiers beginning with underscore and a capital letter, or with two underscores, are reserved for the language implementation. There are many other identifiers you can choose.

Comment: @molbdnilo `wCmd` doesn't point into read-only memory. Not sure why the code isn't using `data()`, though. Or why the code is passing **both** of the first arguments. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you for the tip about the Unicode CreateProcess. I will fix it. The code is passing both arguments because the first is cmd.exe and the second is what it should execute. The goal is to be able to pass "dir c:/mydir" rather than "cmd /c dir c:/mydir".

Comment: AFAIK, neither `popen` nor `system` use cmd.exe for launching a process.

Comment: That's not how `CreateProcess` works. If you need to launch an application with command line arguments, *only* pass `lpCommandLine`. If you need to launch an application without command line arguments, *only* pass `lpApplicationName`. Passing both is only useful for a niche use case that no one is using.

Comment: About `popen` and `system` I was only going by what ChatGPT said (lol, it frequently lies). But there is a difference in that you can send "dir c:/mydir" to `system` and it works. But it does not work with `CreateProcess`. (I haven't tried `popen`.)

Comment: really pass both lpApplicationName and lpCommandLine is full ok. and in this case lpCommandLine can be in read only memory.

Comment: FWIW this code works as is until the ReadFile blocks, whether `CreateProcess` is supposed to work that way or not. That is, the directory listing starts and I get the first 128 bytes of it.

Comment: @rpatters1 so probably cmd wait in call ReadFile and you too

Comment: @RbMm sorry I am confused by your comment, but it sounds promising. Could you be more specific about what you mean?

Comment: if be you simply attach debugger to cmd you view that it wait in call ReadConsoleW

Comment: your error that you inherit more than need. you need use PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_HANDLE_LIST for inherit only hWrite, close it just after process start. not inherit hRead

Comment: and main your error - you need just close hWrite, after call Createprocess. in this case ReadFile not hang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `ReadPipe` is blocking is that `CreateProcess` is calling `cmd.exe` without the `/c` directive. `ReadPipe` is blocking because `cmd.exe` is waiting for user input.

To fix it, simply prepend the `" /c "` to `wCmd` as follows:

```cpp
const std::basic_string<WCHAR> wCmd = L" /c " + __utf8_to_WCHAR(cmd.c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

`ReadFile` is blocking.. but why it must not do this ? if exist data in pipe - `ReadFile` read this data, if no data - it wait for data and block. why/when the read can stop with error ? when **last** handle to other pipe end is closed. you use `hRead`. handle to the other pipe end is `hWrite`. bit you not close own copy of `hWrite` **before** read loop. as result `ReadFile` always will block after some read counts. if you call `CloseHandle(hWrite);` before enter read loop - after cam exit, it copy of `hWrite` will be closed, and pipe broken. `ReadFile` must return with `ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE` error

also use `DETACHED_PROCESS` when create cmd.

```
inline ULONG BOOL_TO_ERROR(BOOL f)
{
    return f ? NOERROR : GetLastError();
}

ULONG TestCmd (_In_ LPWSTR lpCommandLine, _In_opt_ PCWSTR lpCurrentDirectory = 0)
{
    HANDLE hRead, hWrite;

    STARTUPINFOEXW si = {{sizeof(si)}};
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ULONG dwError;
    SIZE_T s;
    while (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == (dwError = BOOL_TO_ERROR(InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(si.lpAttributeList, 1, 0, &s))))
    {
        if (si.lpAttributeList)
        {
            break;
        }
        si.lpAttributeList = (LPPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST)alloca(s);
    }

    if (NOERROR != dwError)
    {
        return dwError;
    }

    if (NOERROR != (dwError = BOOL_TO_ERROR(UpdateProcThreadAttribute(
        si.lpAttributeList, 0, PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_HANDLE_LIST, &hWrite, sizeof(hWrite), 0, 0))))
    {
        return dwError;
    }

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr = { sizeof(saAttr), 0, TRUE };
    if (!CreatePipe(&hRead, &hWrite, &saAttr, 0))
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    si.StartupInfo.hStdError = hWrite;
    si.StartupInfo.hStdOutput = hWrite;
    si.StartupInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    si.StartupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;

    dwError = BOOL_TO_ERROR(CreateProcessW(0, lpCommandLine, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 
        DETACHED_PROCESS|CREATE_NO_WINDOW|EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT, NULL, 
        lpCurrentDirectory, &si.StartupInfo, &pi));

    CloseHandle(hWrite);

    if (NOERROR != dwError)
    {
        return dwError;
    }

    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);

    DWORD bytesRead, dwTotalRead = 0;
    char buffer[0x100];

    while (NOERROR == (dwError = BOOL_TO_ERROR(ReadFile(hRead, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &bytesRead, NULL))))
    {
        DbgPrint("%.*s", bytesRead, buffer);
        dwTotalRead += bytesRead;
    }

    CloseHandle(hRead);

    return ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE == dwError ? NOERROR : dwError;
}

    WCHAR cmd[] = L"cmd /c dir";
    TestCmd(cmd, L"c:\\windows\\system32");
```